# consecutive combination of n things taken k

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let's start my question with a simple example. Suppose I have $4$ apples that are numbered 1 to 4 and I want to to choose $2$ of them.  The first and easy answer is $4C2$ but I want them to be consecutive.  For example if I have $4$ apples and I want to take $2$ of them, I just have $3$ ways to do that in order so my chosen apples are consecutive.
Apple numbers 1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4.
So is there any kind of formula that can calculate this kind of combination?
Sorry if my question is silly and unprofessional.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of possibilities of choosing $k$ consecutive numbers from $n$ numbers is $n-k+1$, since the first number can only be $1,\dots,n-k+1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $n$ apples and want to pick $r$ of them, there are $n-r+1$ ways to do this. Why? Because the leftmost apple you pick determines the rest, and there are $n-r+1$ choices for the leftmost apple, since it must have at least $r-1$ apples to the right of it.